# llegalArgumentException['' is not an IP string literal.];

Tags: elasticsearch

We have field in elasticsearch to hold IP address. 
The data type is :

```
    "privateIpAddress": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "ip"
            }
        }
```

A times, the ip address is not available and instead we receive ' ' (empty string). But when indexing a document with it, ES returns error response :

> Indexing service error, status=failed index=itam-idx1-v1, type=reconciledasset, id=9115314 , Reason Bad Request MapperParsingException[failed to parse [agent.connectedFrom.keyword]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException['' is not an IP string literal.];

Why does ES not allow empty string in ip fields? It allows nulls though.
Is there a way to handle this other than storing null?

Comment: An empty string is not a valid IP address, so the behavior is consistent. Your indexing code should take care of replacing the empty string by a null value if needed.